# How to ingest data from elastic search and query the data in Splunk?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, splunk

I have a project that require me to pull index data from elasticsearch to Splunk. Is it possible?

I came up with the tool called Elasticseach data integrator but its not returning any event i query in Splunk

Comment: By "Elasticsearch data integrator" I assume you mean the Splunk app at "https://splunkbase.splunk.com/app/4175/#/details.  If you've configured the app as documented there, you can contact the developer for support.  There's a link for that on the app page.